# How do I display and update text on multiple device simultaneously php?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to display and update text from the database on multiple devices simultaneously.
once someone enters in the game skip the click button check and enter straight into the game to whichever button the player has pressed.

[heres the site](http://tawedgame.epizy.com/)

**What I have tried:**

I have tried ajax requests to update the text but it only works on one device

```
setInterval(function () {
function here
},500);
```

[my logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FH7Hi.jpg)

Comment: What are you updating if I may ask?

Comment: yeh im just getting results from the database to update the screen on every device that logs into the game

Comment: so when you click a button it spits out a random question from the database then it shows it on only one screen i want it on all logged in screen

Comment: So you can't get the text to update on multiple devices at once?

Comment: yepp im unsure of how to simultaneously update all logged in devices

Comment: Take a look at this, it might  solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16107842/how-to-update-page-content-while-multiple-users-view-it-at-the-same-time-in-php.

Comment: ive seen that but u have to install stuff i was wondering if there is away to do it like a chatting application if that makes sense

Comment: Well I think you could execute an ajax call every let's say 1-2 seconds and update text on a specific website.

Comment: yep but how do u make it display on other devices coz right now it only works on one device

Comment: I'll look into it and give you a response when I'm done.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486885/javascript-and-php-countdown-timer-that-displays-the-same-for-everyone. Also check this out: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/building-real-time-commenting-system/.

Comment: sorry but the magazine one needs a plugin i think and the stack one is setInterval but not one that has a way to use onclick ?

Comment: You could make it work with onclick.

Comment: the problem is i want the same question to display/load on other screens without clicking and then click the button to load a new question then display on other screens without clicking does that make sense?